# Send $_FILES through AJAX, with input multiple

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form with AJAX, containing two variables and an input `type="file"` multiple.
Form works as it should if it's submited in the clasic way.
But when I try to AJAX it, the `$_FILES[]` array comes out empty on the `.php` side.
I've tried everything I know, doesn't work.

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<form action="ajax/process.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="admUploadImg">
<input type="hidden" name="postOp" value="adm-upload-img">
<input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?= $prodData['id'] ?>">
<div class="row my-2 mx-0 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 tb-1 text-left text-sm-right">Imagini 
        <label for="admProdImgs" class="btn btn-success btn-sm p-0 alert-success tip mb-1" title="Adauga imagini"><span class="icon-plus"></span></label>
        <input type="file" multiple id="admProdImgs" name="productImgs[]" class="filestyle invisible" data-form="admUploadImg" required accept="image/jpeg,image/png">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#admUploadImg').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.post('ajax/process.php', formData, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
    console.log(formData);
});
```

However, this generates the following error:

```
TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement interface FormData.
```

So, I've changed the AJAX to that:

```
$('#admUploadImg').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('#admUploadImg').serialize();
    $.post('ajax/process.php', formData, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
    console.log(formData);
});
```

But this time, the `$_FILES[]` array comes empty. 
It's driving me crazy, I have no idea why it doesn't work. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to figure this out, thanks to a comment on another issue, regarding the `formData()` handling.

Turns out everything inside a form is being sent, even from an `onChange` event. The trick is to handle the `formData` corectly, and there were I was geting it wrong.

With this code, I didn't even had to go through `$_FILES[]` from jQuery. I just submited the form as it was.

And I even succeeded to put a progress bar that actually works. :)

Here's the **Javascript code**

```
$('#admUploadImg').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    showFadeProgress();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url : "ajax/process.php",
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
                $('#admFilesUpload').css({width: Math.floor(e.loaded / e.total *100) + '%'});
            };
            return xhr;
        },
        type: "POST",
        data : formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(response){
            $('#admProdImages').html(response);
            setTimeout(function(){
                restoreFadePopup();
            },100);
        }
    });
});
```

The `showFdeProgress()` function just shows a modal with the message and the progress bar.

The `restoreFadePopup()` function close that modal after the whole processing is done.

For #Tanner Babcock, don't know what to say, I didn't test your code, I already came with this sollution, but I'll upVote your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This example is based on what I use, it works for me. I would suggest making a button or something, as there doesn't seem to be any visual element that a user could use to submit the form (although this might be intentional).

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="admUploadImg" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="postOp" value="adm-upload-img" />
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?= $prodData['id'] ?>" />
    <div class="row my-2 mx-0 justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-2 tb-1 text-left text-sm-right">Imagini 
            <label for="admProdImgs" class="btn btn-success btn-sm p-0 alert-success tip mb-1" title="Adauga imagini"><span class="icon-plus"></span></label>
            <input type="file" multiple id="admProdImgs" name="productImgs[]" class="filestyle invisible" data-form="admUploadImg" required accept="image/jpeg,image/png">
        </div>
        <button id="go">Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Since you're using Ajax and not uploading the form with traditional HTML, you will want to remove the `action="ajax/process.php"` attribute. This keeps the form from submitting in the traditional way. Here's the JavaScript.

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
    var f = $("#admUploadImg")[0];
    var form_data = new FormData(f);
    
    var file_data = $("#admProdImgs").prop("files");
    $.each(file_data, function(index, value) {
        form_data.append("productImgs", file_data[index]);
    });
    // unsure about this part, maybe try "productImgs[]" if the above doesn't work
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "ajax/process.php",
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    console.log(form_data);
});
```

I've changed the above JavaScript to the `.click()` event for **`#go`**, the button. I also switched to an [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call instead of a `.post()` call. You wouldn't think `dataType: "text"` would work, but that is what works for me. What I use on my own website is almost the same thing, only my form takes only 3 individual `<input type="file" />` elements. I tried to implement [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through all of the files the user might have selected.